# Which of these drivers would help my computer resume from suspend?

Tags: 14.04, graphics, suspend

When I resume from suspend, I get a garbled display for a half-minute and then I will either get to the lock screen for the session I had or else booted back to the greeter, with my session and open applications/files lost.

Would switching to Noveau help this? I'm asking because the last time I went fiddling with the dialog shown below I ended up not able to get a desktop at all and having to reinstall.

I've pasted the output of dmesg here|: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/11626556/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia-304 drivers badly support old 7xxx video adapters. 
There may be other issues, not only with suspend.

I suggest using Nouveau (last one) or nvidia-173.

Nvidia-173 may perform a little better, but nouveau has a decent support of 7xxx.

Try both. Leave the one, which performs better.

If you have Ubuntu 14.04.2, nvidia-173 will not install.

You will have to lower the version of xserver to original in 14.04.

This can be done by

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg libgles1-mesa libgles2-mesa libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers

Then nvidia-173 should install by

sudo apt-get install nvidia-173
```

Comment: Thanks Pilot6. Well before I saw your answer I tried Noveau and my sessions kept locking up completely after login. No keyboard, no mouse. I had to do a hard reboot. So I'm back on nvidia-304 for now for my MSI 7600 GT. But I will try 173 now that you mention it, thank you.

Comment: Trying 173 gave problems: nvidia-173: Depends: x11-common (>= 1:7.0.0) but 1:7.7+1ubuntu8.1 is to be installed
            Depends: xorg-video-abi-15 but it is a virtual package. So looks like I'm stuck with 304.

Comment: You are not stuck. Do you have a 32- or 64-bit system?

Comment: My installation is 64-bit.

Comment: I updated the answer. 173 will be better.

Comment: I was left at a blinking cursor so I went back to 304. But thanks for your answer, I've learned a lot about changing configuration without a gui.